# Canvas Drawing Flickring

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I'm hoping that somebody with  drawing experience can help me figure out why, in the following example, I'm seeing occasional flickering of the dots. I'm at a loss here. Thanks for any possible suggestions.

http://codepen.io/mikefowler/pen/fLHAB

Comment: Dont ask me why, but when you change the minimum of the opacity to 0.001 it works. I will investigate a little and try to find a reason

Comment: Well look at that. Good catch! Strange though, I'd love to know why that is.

Comment: Is it only flickering in Mozilla? Because that's the only browser I can reproduce the issue in.

Comment: Nope, before I updated the pen linked above it was reproducing in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newOpacity` is at times so small that numbers like `9.444794391022526e-9` will occure as newOpacity, `'rgba(r,g,b,a)'` will most likely parse this wrong, as you are creating a string there.
You could use a custom `Math.round()` but since you're working with a string you can do a simple

```
newOpacity = newOpacity.toFixed(2);
```

Or instead of 2 you can use whatever number of decimals you want, after the 3rd decimal you won't see a difference in alpha anyways.